# How much anonymity can you have on Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, privacy

I don't see the option to have your name as just "anonymous" like on [Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora). Is there an equivalent to that on here? Or if not, what's the next best thing?

Comment: You don't. Once you post something, you must provide some sort of email (even as unregistered user) that can be used at some point to trace you back, even if only by SE employees. If you care so much about those things, stay anonymous visitor behind ever changing IP and don't post anything. Good luck!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think there is a case to be made for maximizing one's anonymity on SE. I should stress that "maximum anonymity on SE" does not necessarily mean "complete anonymity on SE", and does not mean "lack of accountability". But since we have SE sites about politics and various religions, one could have a perfectly valid question or answer that one would prefer to post anonymously. So, I think if this question was changed to "how can I maximize anonymity on SE", it would be a good question for Meta.

Comment: @S.L.Barth he clearly says "complete anonymity". As for what you said, it's easy enough to register several accounts. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's why I suggest changing the question. And I guess "forget about rep and badges, use a different account for every post" would be part of the answer...

Comment: I don't wanna change it. I'm sorry.

Comment: Fair enough. You know best what your wishes and/or needs are.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thanks, that's probably one of the nicest things I've heard on here so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enhance your anonymity by:

- using Stack Exchange only in browser private mode
- register using e-mail registered in browser private mode
- don't ever give any real data for either accounts, or even the data similar to your real ones

However, you can always be tracked by [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), your [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) provider's logs. To go step further, you must assure, your ISP doesn't know who you are and can't figure it out:

- use Stack Exchange only from mobile Internet
- buy a pre-paid card that doesn't require registration, at least far away from your place of living or by third persons
- use those cards only far away from the place you live, never activate them near your house

Comment: How do you use SE in private mode?

Comment: @softwareninja browser private mode. It isn't as important, anyway, as long you can be sure noone is using your laptop or don't fear police confiscating it.

Comment: Like [Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en) in chrome?

Comment: @softwareninja yes, it has various names depending on browser, in one it was р0rи0 mode ^^

Comment: Item 2 (email) is easily accomplished with [10 minute mail](http://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html) which requires no registration.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills If you use a site like 10 minute mail is there anyway you could be detected and deleted off of here automatically? I can at least think of a couple more websites that allow you to do the same thing.

Comment: @softwareninja To my understanding, SE does not object to users giving fake emails at registration. You can use 10-minute-mail, or you can enter `a@b.cc` as email address (not sure if the latter works on SO, where the rules are a bit tighter). Case in point: the "email address" of my account is `there@you.go`... A potential downside is that you won't be able to prove account ownership if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

You already gave up a fair amount of anonymity by registering for a Stack Exchange account.

Beyond that, the following things could identify your Stack Exchange account to people who know you:

- Posting the actual code you're working with (another reason to always construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
- Using language which would fairly uniquely identify you
- Posting any personal information on any of your Stack Exchange profiles
- Speaking from identifiable personal experience in any of your posts
- Having an exact overlap between what people know you work with and what type of questions you're asking / answering on Stack Exchange (e.g. if people know you work with Java, C++ and Prolog, being active in exactly those tags might be an indicator)
- Being compromised on the machine you're using a Stack Exchange site on. This could range from having someone walk past behind you when you're posting a post, having spyware installed by your employer, or whatever really

Although, keep in mind that there are a ton of users on most Stack Exchange sites. Unless one can absolutely conclusive say that it's you, there's a high probability that it's not you, so any reasonable person wouldn't jump to conclusions. And you should also keep in mind that most people probably don't care enough to try to figure out whether you have a Stack Exchange account, or who some Stack Exchange account belongs to.